# Need to check a code if it is not checked in last 24 hours

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

i need to check a block of code only once per day, i tried the below code but it is not working as per my requirement. like today date is 25-5-2017 and last checked date is 23-5-2017 also it is not coming inside the condition. i don't know where i am doing wrong.

```
            NSDate *todayDate = [NSDate date];
            NSLog(@"today date is %@",todayDate);
            NSDate *lastCheckedDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"LastCheckedDate"];
            NSLog(@"lastCheckedDate is %@",lastCheckedDate);
            if ([todayDate compare:lastCheckedDate] > 864000.0f) {
                NSArray *appMsgsArray = [response valueForKey:@"AppMsgs"];
                NSDictionary *mainDict = [appMsgsArray objectAtIndex:0];
                NSString *appDataExpiry = [mainDict valueForKey:@"appdata_expiry"];
                [stm deleteOldArticles:[appDataExpiry integerValue]];
                NSDate *lastDate = [NSDate date];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:lastDate forKey:@"LastCheckedDate"];
            }
```

for one day i am using 864000.0f value. can anyone help me for this, thank you.

Comment: when you say "once a day"... do you mean that there have to be at least 24 hours passed since the last check?

Comment: yes, after 24 hours passed only i need to do that process. @AndréSlotta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
NSDate *firstDate = [NSDate date];
NSDate *secondDate = [NSDate date];

if ([secondDate timeIntervalSinceDate:firstDate] >= 86400) {
    NSLog(@"24 hours have passed...");
}
```

Comment: NSDate *todayDate = [NSDate date];
                NSDate *lastCheckedDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"LastCheckedDate"];
                
                if ([lastCheckedDate timeIntervalSinceDate:todayDate] >= 864000) {
                }  today date is 2017-05-25 07:40:28 +0000, lastCheckedDate is 2017-05-23 07:35:04 +0000

Comment: you have to switch the dates! `[todayDate timeIntervalSinceDate:lastCheckedDate]`...

Comment: and there are only 86400 seconds for 24 hours not 864000

Comment: that's true, @raki :)

Comment: after changing that 864000 to 86400 it works guyz, Thank you @raki and André Slotta